What does "this problem" refer to?
I found the essay question below on a website. Is it clear what this problem refers to? Does it refer to the entire first sentence, the housing shortages or the social consequences? Can the singular 'this problem' refer to the plural 'housing shortages' or 'social consequences'?
Should it be phrased as 'the housing shortage in big cities' or 'the shortage of housing in big cities' to avoid unambiguity?

Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences.
Some people think that only government action can solve this problem.
To what extent do you agree or disagree?


@Lambie, I think it refers to 'housing shortages' but 'housing shortages' is plural while "this problem" is singular so I am not sure.

Saying there are housing shortages does not mean you can't refer to it as This problem. These problems would be something like: Housing shortage and unemployment are major social problems. //The burnt apples are the main problem [singular] with the recipe. housing is used attributively.

this problem refers to the fact that Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences. As in It is a problem that Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences.

@FumbleFingers, I understand your explanation this way. The question asks if we agree that social consequences caused by housing shortages in big cities can be solved only through government action. So, 'this problem' refers to social consequences caused by housing shortages in big cities? In essence, it refers to the social consequences?

No - like I said, "this problem" refers to the fact that Housing shortages in big cities [can] cause severe social consequences. It may well be true that those social consequences are problems / a problem themselves, but that's not what the words "this problem" refer to.

...it's not very well written, though. Generally we say circumstances / actions have consequences. Causing consequences sounds "tautological" to me.

@FumbleFingers There is absolulely nothing wrong with: Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences. And I repeat: this problem refers to the housing shortages or the whole sentence. It could not be clearer. The fact that is singular is irrelevant.

@Lambie, which is more likely, the housing shortages or the whole sentence?

It's all part of the same idea. The whole thing. But specifically housing shortages. I just don't understand questions like this because whatever your native language is, it would have the same pragmatic issues.

@Lambie: this problem refers to ... the whole sentence is exactly the same as my "this problem" refers to the fact that Housing shortages in big cities [can] cause severe social consequences.

@FumbleFingers Sure, but you always seem to make everything more complicated. In any case, it would the same in any language.

@Lambie: You don't like to give an inch, do you? My first comment exactly covered the issue, but the OP asked for clarification, so I clearly asserted that it would be incorrect to ascribe "this problem" to "Housing shortages". As it happens, the semantics of the exact example would allow that interpretation, but that's a syntactically sloppy approach. Suppose instead the text had started with "Increased levels of immigration" rather than "Housing shortages". You'd be seriously twisting the writer's intent if you said those "Increased levels of immigration" were the same as "this problem".

Considering:

"Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences",

if that were generalized to
"X can cause severe social consequences"
or
"something can cause severe social consequences"
then clearly the something is a problem.
As a fantastical experiment, let's imagine for a moment "this problem" referred only to "severe social consequences".   The government action ought to solve the problem (severe social consequences) while at the same time leaving the "housing shortage" untouched.
That could make sense in an alternate universe, where cities solved housing shortages by bussing 30% of their residents to another state in order to get rid of them.  The problem is solved without addressing the cause.
But in reality, that is nonsense. If the paragraph is intended to make sense rationally, the government action will not be killing the extra residents or forcibly removing them.  Rather, it should be focused on "the problem" which is the "housing shortage".
It's equally valid to say the problem is the whole thing, the entire sentence: "Housing shortages in big cities can cause severe social consequences", since essentially that means the same thing, if you think about what it means. How can there by any confusion?
If we generalize further, to the form: "X causes Y. Z can solve the problem."  In that case, you need to know what X and Y are.  Sometimes the "problem" is Y. Sometimes it's X. And sometimes the whole sentence explains what the problem is.
